# Block Google from indexing a particular image

Tags: indexing, wordpress

I have a image on the about us page which I do not want Google to index in its images engine. Is there a easy way to do this? The website is built using Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Prevent Images from your site showing up in Google's Image query items, add a robots.txt file to the root of the server that obstructs the picture. It takes more time to remove a picture from query items than the Remove URLs device, yet is an Internet standard that applies to all internet searchers, and you have more adaptable control through the utilization of special cases or subpath blocking.

Case in point, on the off chance that you need Google to exclude the abc.jpg picture that shows up on your site at www.yoursite.com/images/abc.jpg, add the accompanying to your robots.txt document:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image

Disallow: /images/abc.jpg

Whenever Google crawl your site, we'll see this mandate and drop your picture from our list items.

To uproot all the pictures on your site from our record, put the accompanying robots.txt document in your server root:

To remove all the images on your site from our index, place the following robots.txt file in your server root:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image

Disallow: /

Additionally, Google has introduced increased flexibility to the robots.txt file standard through the use asterisks. Disallow patterns may include "*" to match any sequence of characters, and patterns may end in "$" to indicate the end of a name. To remove all files of a specific file type (for example, to include .jpg but not .gif images), you'd use the following robots.txt entry:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image

Disallow: /*.gif$

By specifying Googlebot-Image as the User-agent, the images will be excluded from Google Image Search. It will also prevent cropping of the image for display within Mobile Image Search, as the image will be completely removed from Google's Image index. If you would like to exclude the images from all Google searches (including Google web search and Google Images), specify User-agent Googlebot.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! One extra question related though - I use the Wordpress SEO by Yoast, will this get affected by me adding a robots.txt file?

Comment: i think no issue regarding that